# Issue in populating the fields in angular js 9

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have an accordion and expansion panel in angular application. I am able to add the expansion panels dynamically with some fields. When i click on the `<p>` tag, i should open the same pop up with the values in the expansion panel. It is like "Updating the data in the expansion panel". The issue is, when i click on the p tag, it is opening with empty fields. Kindly help me in populating the existing data.

The stackblitz url is [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-expansion-panel-pdsahp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was you were not passing any data which SequenceDialogBoxComponent can display, so when you are creating the component by calling this method addNewSequenceStep store the values somewhere and when you are calling openNewSequenceStepDialog on click of p, pass those values as subject key inside obj which you have bind inside HTML of SequenceDialogBoxComponent and you component will be able to display data.

Here is stackbliz url for you reference: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-expansion-panel-demo?file=src/app/app.component.ts)